# Characterizing a PIN photodiode's 3 dB bandwidth

Tags: photodiode, optoelectronics, photosensor, photonics

I'm currently attempting to characterize a PIN photodiode's 3 dB bandwidth. The photodiode input is a laser source that is being modulated by an ESA RF output that performs a frequency sweep from 0-1.5 GHz. The output of the photodiode is then connect to a 50 Ω resistor which is connected to ground. The ESA input terminals are connected over the 50 Ω resistor. I have two pertinent questions:

1. The spec sheet gives a 3 dB BW of 0.7 GHz. Can a regular breadboard be used for the circuit? Currently, I have the legs of the components connected together and the components themselves in air, since I read that the parasitics of the breadboard will interfere with the measurements. I did attempt to measure it with the breadboard and didn't notice a large increase in noise.
2. I'm using a 50 Ω resister since the input of the ESA is also 50 Ω. However, I'm still getting RF reflections in the output spectrum. I'm unfamiliar with RF circuits and measurement. How would I go about matching the impedance in a better manner?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

[image: Normalized Frequency Response][Photodiode Data Sheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/38819/Agilent(Hewlett-Packard)/PDT0412-FC-A/1)

The modulation is the power sweep function from the HP L1500A:
[image]

**!**
**Edit**
Previously I was using a Pulse Pattern Generator to modulate the LASER. I increased the PPG frequency until the spectrum amplitude rolled off to 1/sqrt2 value. This issue was that the spectrum was extremely noisy, and near impossible to get an accurate reading of the roll off.

Comment: How do you know you're getting output reflections?  Can you show us whatever scope traces, TDA outputs, or spectrum analyzer outputs that lead you to believe this is happening?

Comment: While you're editing your question with the above information, could you also give us the part number of the photodiode.  Look through the data sheet and make sure that they don't document the test fixture they used to get their measurements -- that's pretty common, especially when the specifications are this tight.

Comment: A photograph of your test setup would be good, too -- those reflections may be in the optical path.

Comment: I don't feel I can fully answer this question, but a big part of the answer is that your test fixture needs to start with a purpose-designed board with impedance-controlled traces, with connectors that are good up or beyond the highest frequency you're applying.  Wires floating in space are not going to cut it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Tim. The datasheet is linked below the spectrum plot. I can take a photo of the test setup, but it's extremely messy. Our lab is short on room so I'm essentially doing the experiment on a chair. I also have a photo of the diode connections, but as they're just the legs of the components wrapped around each other, so I'm going to assume that won't cut it. I'll work on cleaning up the workspace and get a picture shortly. Do you mind recommending a textbook or resource?

Comment: Messy test setup... is unlikely to work here. Lay out a test PCB, then ask for a design review, since it will need one :)

Comment: The spectrum analyzer already has a 50 ohm resistor internally, so you don't need to add a second one (although if you choose to this will probably result in higher bandwidth than if you'd 50 ohm terminated it due to lower RC delay). Your frequency response also looks very strange, I would double check that your laser is being modulated the way you think it is.

Comment: A breadboard is not ok. Everything needs to be controlled impedance, so either a PCB or else solder the diode directly across a 50 ohm cable (cut off the connector) with the shortest possible leads. Use a battery for the bias voltage.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with PCBs. Should I simply search for an RF or Microwave PCB? Also, thanks everyone for the feedback. The post has been edited to include more information as well.

Comment: If you're not comfortable designing the PCB, then you should solder directly to a coax, which is functionally the same thing. However, to really use the bandwidth of these diodes you'll probably need to design a PCB. This is not something you'll find in a catalog.

Comment: Can I buy a blank microwave/RF rated PCB and solder to it? (Sorry if the question is overly simplistic, I looked online and had trouble finding out if that route is reasonable). Or is it better to design it so that the photodiode is already included?

Comment: You are missing the point. Since the photodiode response depends on the circuit, normally you would design the circuit you want  to use the diode in and then evaluate performance. If you don't care about the circuit, then just solder to a coax. Maybe you could find an evaluation board that connected to a coax cable, but you'd still have to solder so not much point.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse biased photo diode is almost a perfect current source with a small capacitance across it. Then AC wise the 2 load resistors shunts the diode so the bandwidth is essentially 1/2/pi/R/C where C is the photo diodes capacitance and R is, in your case 25 Ohms.

The only time you get reflections is when a transmission line of sufficient length is involved. Just connecting a 100 Ohm resistor, say across a 50 Ohm resistor doesn't cause reflections.

My guess is that you are showing the spectrum of a ~100 MHz signal that is turning the light on and off, and therefore the photodiode current on and off, essentially. You don't really mention what sort of light source you are using, but if you want to measure the frequency response you have to vary the frequency of modulation on the (fiber coupled LASER I assume). If you are using a sguare wave to modulate the LASER then only pay attention to the fundamental frequency, Also I suggest turning down the modulation of the light to an optical modulation index of around 50%.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I added more information about the modulation in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The spectrum we see is not the typical output of a power sweep. That would bt a plot of output level vs input level. The slope at small inputs would be the small signal gain, And as the input increases, eventually the gain falls off, the slope becomes less, and the point where the actual output level is 1 dB below where the small signal gain line would be is the 1 dB compression point. Instead we see a spectrum of non linear signal. It is not  a frequency response. No pin diode detector and laser source would have such a response.    The L1500 tracking generator should be set on frequency sweep, like testing a filter and the power level should be set to a level that keeps the source linear. Then the plot will be a scaler frequency response of the network, not a spectrum.